# Star Wars Saga Edition; Cover and blocking LoS

Tags: ranged-attack, star-wars-saga-edition, prone, line-of-sight, cover

My group encountered a big problem. Our DM made us fight some enemies (level 5 or so) that used to take cover behind crates/walls/even cars, and used the following order of actions:

-move to cover
-standard action shoot
-swift action to go prone

second round they would do something like:

-move to get up
-standard action shoot
-swift action to go prone

basically, this made all of the opponents out of Line of Sight, since they were always prone behind something. Now this led to a lot of "ready actions", and prolonged firefights. It also made most special abilities useless and prevented aiming, while also making multiattack a total waste.

Is he playing this right? according to the rules this works. Maybe they are designed to work like this? Thanks for your attention folks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the rules:

> Being prone may also give a character total cover instead of normal cover (for example, being prone behind a low wall), subject to the GM's discretion.

So yes, this can work. But not in every situation, with every kind of cover. For example, dropping prone around a corner shouldn't provide any more cover than standing erect around it.

Dropping prone behind a <strike>car</strike> landspeeder should *remove* cover. Remember: in Star Wars, cars *float* ;) Admittedly not that high, but if you're 20 feet away, you should be able to see under them with no problem.

Your group's use of readying actions are a perfectly valid way of dealing with this. But you should also remember that you can ready *any* standard or move action (though oddly, not a swift action, so you can't drop prone). So you can employ many of your powers even when enemies are using this tactic.

Using AoE effects can also work. The rules on auto-fire AOE attacks are a bit odd on cover. Auto-fire weapons won't work if the cover can withstand the fire, but a thrown grenade, as in real life, can flush people out of cover quite effectively.

But most important of all, you need to remember to use your advantages: *mobility*. By sacrificing their move action just to stand up, they are limiting themselves to being able to shoot *or* move, but not both. If you advance forward, even if you don't get around their cover that turn, they have to make a choice. They can either get up and run (burn their standard action to move) or shoot you. But they can't shoot and move in the same turn.

Oh, and FYI: if you want to try this trick yourself, being trained in Acrobatics allows you to stand up as a swift action, thus allowing you to retain the option of moving and shooting.

Comment: Very good answer, thanks a lot. Yeah, outmanouvering becomes really important, but it's a kinda slow process and can bog a fight down. I noticed that many objects that can give out cover can be broken/blown up. Heavy blaster rifle with autofire/rapid shot or similar attacks can easily destroy small/thin walls, crates and so on. Melee is also a valid option, as they are prone the jedi or melee soldier that can reach them is going to hit the enemy with a juicy +5 to hit bonus.

Answer (score 1):

Although I'm not intimately familliar with Saga Edition, yes, the sequence of actions sounds correct, and actually mimics a real world firefight, to a certain extent (although, in the real world, people would likely be just ducking behind the cover, rather than going prone).

Your group's choice of using ready actions was one solution to the problem. Borrowing from the real world again, and depending on the layoutof the area, moving to flanking positions and providing [enfilading fire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enfilade_and_defilade) may also have helped negate the enemy cover.

Comment: good mate, thnks a lot for the answer. The problem is that it bogs down the combat a lot into single shots with cover bonuses making hitting very hard, and with HPs a single battle can last around 45 minutes or more, even with average enemies. Maybe blasting the cover is the best idea when an opponent is behind something that can be destroyed.